# ¿Error al registrar en el método ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, sql-server

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

He realizado un registrar usando C# mvc y ajax pero al momento de realizar el post en jquery ajax, me devuelve el error en consola, no entra a `Success` pero si `error`.

Formulario html

```
<form id="idForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idNombres">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres" id="idNombres" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idApellidos">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="idApellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idEdad">Edad</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="edad" id="idEdad" placeholder="Edad">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idImagen">Adjuntar</label>
        <input type="file" name="imageLoad" id="idImagen" accept="image/*" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btnRegistrar">Guardar</button>

</form>
```

Método registrar en controller.

```
public void registrar(Persona persona)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase fileBase = Request.Files[0];
            WebImage image = new WebImage(fileBase.InputStream);
            persona.imagen = image.GetBytes();
            _repo.Agregar(persona);
            _repo.Guardar();

        }
```

Ajax en JQuery

```
    registrar: function () {
        var form = new FormData($("#idForm")[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: './Persona/registrar',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                window.location = "./Home";
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err); //Entra Aquí
            }
        });
    }
```

Sí me registra la información en la base de datos pero en el `ajax` no entra a `success`. Entra `error` y me devuelver error

Esta es mi Tabla de Base de datos SQL Server
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imprimo el error en consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error Encontrado.

```
El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección
```

Pero Aun así se registra la imagen en la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Le falto agregar el error; si el `alert` le devuelve que es un objeto usa `console.log(err)`  para ver el mensaje.

Comment: ya se actualizo la  pregunta.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Prueba omitiendo `window.location = "./Home";` que no se ejecute; me parece todo esta bien; puede ser que de tu ruta actual (donde invocas el Ajax) el `./Home` no existe.

Comment: Ese no es el problema, sigue direccionandolo a error.

Comment: si usas el developer tools del browser, pero la solapa "networks" podrias ver la llamada a la url y ver que esta retornando como error. La imagen que muestras no veo el error https://cybmeta.com/manejo-de-errores-en-jquery-ajax si revisas veras que el error de $.ajax tiene mas parametros que por ahi aporten el mensaje por el cual falla. Ademas el endpoint que invocas porque no le defines el [HttpPost]

Comment: Registra correctamente a la base de datos pero en 'success', deseo que redireccione la pagina al index, pero nunca entra a 'success', va al evento error del ajax.

Comment: No encuentro el error

Comment: En el método Registrar, te falta devolver una respuesta Json

Comment: es un método void

Comment: El AJAX espera una respuesta JSON.. sin esa respuesta siempre dará error

Comment: Eso era el problema que no devolvía ningún valor, por ello retornaba al error en el ajax, gracias.